# Firebase Dynamic link internal error when creating using curl

Tags: firebase, curl, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

i am trying to create firebase dynamic link using curl:

```curl
curl -d '{
        "dynamicLinkInfo": {
            "domainUriPrefix": "https://someweb.page.link",
            "link": "https://www.someWeb.net/shops?referral_id=someReferralId",
            "androidInfo": {
                "androidPackageName": "some package name"
            },
            "iosInfo": {
                "iosBundleId": "some bundle",
                "iosAppStoreId": "11111111"
            },
            "navigationInfo": {
                "enableForcedRedirect": true
            }
        }
    }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=MyFBWebKey"
```

and for some reason, I'm getting the following response with isn't very explanatory...

*{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}*

I've tried to delete all the iosInfo, navigationInfo, androidInfo... and the problem persists. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as i know error 500 is on the server side. If you don't control the server yourself you should contact the one that does control it.

Comment: I notice that the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener#request_body) use `domainUriPrefix`, as you do, but the example in [the guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_a_long_link) uses `dynamicLinkDomain`.  You could try using `dynamicLinkDomain`.

Comment: Is `someweb.page.link` the domain created for your app and shown in your project's Dynamic Links data in the Firebase Console?  Also, try specifying the domain without `https://`, i.e.`"domainUriPrefix": "someweb.page.link"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, Bob, I used dynamicLinkDomain instead of domainUriPrefix as mentioned in the documentation and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I remove these lines and it works

```
"androidInfo": {
            "androidPackageName": "some package name"
},
```

if I find out the way to work with android data, I will update the answer for android